# How can I program an ESP 10 module

Tags: esp8266

I buy an ESP-10 module and I want to upload custom room to its flash. The problem is that there is no way to access GPIO 0 pin! Is there some way around it to upload custom room without connecting GPIO 0 to the ground? 
How in the earth should I program it without this pin?
here is an address to supplier's page which contains schematic and some other details.
https://www.tindie.com/products/George/esp8266-esp-10-module/#product-description

Comment: you can't. io 0 and io 2 are on this board connected and pulled up together

Comment: why are they connected? what is the purpose of this module?

Comment: for normal operation io 0 and io 2 must be pulled HIGH at startup. for flashing mode mode io 0 must be LOW and io 2 HIGH

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Not without physical modification to the PCB itself (remove the chip, scratch off a pad and trace, replace pad with fine enamelled copper wire tinned at the end, replace chip).  All you can use is whatever firmware is currently installed in the module.